# SQL Writing Result to XML when failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
 SELECT   
    (SELECT v_value as "@value", columnname as "@columnname", 
            updatedby as "@updatedby", emailid as "@emailid",
            updatedon as "@updatedon"              
     from nodetable, Progresss PGA, mastertable 
     where columnname ='SSNNO' 
           and PGA.ProjId=9 
           AND OBSID IN (SELECT NodeId FROM projecttable 
                         WHERE ParentId=mastertable.roles AND Title='some value') 
           AND UserId=1 
           AND mastertable.FileID=nodetable.fileid 
           AND mastertable.FileID=821  
     ORDER BY updatedon desc  FOR XML PATH('Forms'), TYPE)
 FOR XML PATH('Form'), TYPE
```

This is my query for getting the XML.. Don't worry its works fine..

But my problem if the condition fails I want to print the one more tag that it always tells what happened in the query..

Like for this query if all the conditions succeed I'll get complete XML..

Else I'll get

```
 <Form />
```

But I want to print result like in failure case..

```
<Form SUCCESS="0"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @XML XML =
    (SELECT v_value as "@value", columnname as "@columnname", 
            updatedby as "@updatedby", emailid as "@emailid",
            updatedon as "@updatedon"              
     from nodetable, Progresss PGA, mastertable 
     where columnname ='SSNNO' 
           and PGA.ProjId=9 
           AND OBSID IN (SELECT NodeId FROM projecttable 
                         WHERE ParentId=mastertable.roles AND Title='some value') 
           AND UserId=1 
           AND mastertable.FileID=nodetable.fileid 
           AND mastertable.FileID=821  
     ORDER BY updatedon desc  FOR XML PATH('Forms'))

IF @XML IS NULL
  SELECT CAST('<Form SUCCESS="0"/>' AS XML)
ELSE
  SELECT @XML FOR XML PATH('Form')
```

As one statement

```
SELECT CASE WHEN T.X IS NULL THEN 0 END AS [@SUCCESS],
       T.X AS [*]
FROM 
    (SELECT v_value as "@value", columnname as "@columnname", 
            updatedby as "@updatedby", emailid as "@emailid",
            updatedon as "@updatedon"              
     from nodetable, Progresss PGA, mastertable 
     where columnname ='SSNNO' 
           and PGA.ProjId=9 
           AND OBSID IN (SELECT NodeId FROM projecttable 
                         WHERE ParentId=mastertable.roles AND Title='some value') 
           AND UserId=1 
           AND mastertable.FileID=nodetable.fileid 
           AND mastertable.FileID=821  
     ORDER BY updatedon desc  FOR XML PATH('Forms'), TYPE) AS T(X)
FOR XML PATH('Form'), TYPE
```

Comment: yes its works.. can't i do it just with select statement...? without making it as procedure...?any idea is appreciated..

Comment: @Rocky111 - You can use first version without creating a stored procedure.